# What type of encoding is this? \u00e2\u0098\u0085 it is supposed to translate into ★

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

"\u00e2\u0098\u0085" is supposed to translate into "★"

What type of encoding is it?
I first thought that it was an unicode escape sequence but when I use a converter I get "â"
I have also gone the other way around and tried different converters using the "★" symbol to try and get that encoding but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear where the `\u00e2\u0098\u0085` string comes from. However, running the following in *Python* prompt gives desired result:

```
b"\u00e2\u0098\u0085".decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode()
```

> ```
> '★'
> ```

```
"\\u00e2\\u0098\\u0085".encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode()
```

> ```
> '★'
> ```

Note that `.encode()` is an equivalent for `.encode('utf-8')` (and the same for `.decode()`).

Answer (score 0):

When I encode ★ as UTF-8, I get `\xE2\x98\x85`.  (Not `\u00e2\u0098\u0085`.  You have 16 bit values where you should have 8 bit value.)

So what you have there is an **incorrect** encoding that is (in effect):

1. Encoding the Unicode code point as UTF-8
2. Treating the UTF-8 *code values* (bytes) as Unicode code points and re-encoding them as UTF-16.

Or alternatively:

1. Encoding the Unicode code point as UTF-8
2. Decoding it as (say) LATIN-8

But however you look at it, that is the result of an **incorrect** sequence of encode / decode steps ... somewhere.